# android opening facebook app on a specific post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

I am working on an application that fetches posts from user stream (from stream table) and displays them.

streams post_id fields are returned in the format of: {uid}_{postid}, e.g.:

```
100001147753406_320951738012113
```

How can I open facebook application to show such post?

in web browser this can be done with the url: www.facebook.com/uid/posts/postid, and according to searches this should be accomplished by setting Intent's uri to:

```
fb://post/{postid}?owner={uid}
```

However, this does not always work from intent.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Ah. My bad. That I have no idea about. Sorry. I will withdraw this post, see if I can find a solution and update if I do. ;-)

Comment: Have u found a solution because I'm trying to find out how to exactly the same thing.

Comment: Is the returned post id (using graph api) is the same id you found when you hover with mouse over the post time (using pc browser)? In my case they are different and when I try to open the post using your approach it fails. knowing that the returned posts ids are not in the form of uid_postId it's just the postId.

Answer (score 1):

After messing around with the different options, this simple format finally worked for me:

```
fb://post/{postid}
```

Where the post id is the entire {x_id}_{y_id} string, e.g.:

```
fb://post/100001147753406_320951738012113
```